# Android ndk-build error make.exe: *** create_child_process: DuplicateHandle(In) failed (e=6)

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, ndk-build

I'm relatively new to Android and I have a problem using the ndk-build command.
I use the NDK r9d under Windows 7 64bits.

When I run my build system which creates my Android project (makefiles etc...) and then creates a process running ndk-build.cmd (I checked that it is call in the Android project) I get the error:

**make.exe: *** create_child_process: DuplicateHandle(In) failed (e=6)**

But when I run ndk-build.cmd "manually" in the windows command console in the same Android project created by my build system (or any Android project) everything is working.

I did find some related questions like here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014825836

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2004-09/msg01506.html

But all I found says either that it's a problem of make version which is not (I think) since ndk-build works fine when I use it "manually" or it says that it is related to stdin handling and again I don't think that the issue here. Plus all the anwsers that I found was related to a similar error but not exactly the same:

process_easy: DuplicateHandle(In) failed (e=6)

Maybe someone knows the meaning of my error message. I don't think that's specific to Android ndk-build but maybe.

Thank you for reading (and sorry for any english mistakes, I am french and not fluent in english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly, I found a solution to my problem here:

http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=174

I am not sure about what the problem was but according to this link, it was related to the make environment and the handles.

The solution : Instead of using the createProcess function (from Windows) directly to call ndk-build.cmd, I created a batch file containing:

start ndk-build.cmd

And I called this batch (.bat) via the createProcess function.

I let you see the link for more details.