# make command fails when launched via CreateProcess but command line on Windows 7

Tags: cmd, makefile, 64-bit, windows-7-x64, 32-bit

I'm witnessing this weird behavior from make.exe on Windows 7.

If I launch directly from the command line as "make -j8 some-component-name",
the command does succeed.

If I launch the same from a C program using CreateProcess(.......) inheriting
all the environment, etc from the parent, I see that it fails with the below
error message:

**make[4]: *** create_child_process: DuplicateHandle(In) failed (e=6).
Stop.**

Here's what I have tried so far -- all of them anyway didn't help.

1. Through CreateProcess() both 32-bit and 64-bit cmd.exe have been
   tried to launch the make command.
2. Built the C program as 32-bit and also 64-bit.
3. Tried CreateProcess("c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe", "/C make -j8
   some-component-name", ..)
4. Tried CreateProcess(NULL, "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C make
   -j8 some-component-name", ..)
5. Tried CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe /C make -j8 some-component-name",
   ..)

Things I haven't tried but thought of, though not sure if they can fix the problem:

1. Using ShellExecute() in place of CreateProcess().

By the way, the make utility is from GNU make package. And I tried using
two versions of make 3.81 and 2.something.something. Also I made sure that
there's only one make.exe accessible to run in a command prompt.

So, any ideas on where things are going wrong?

Thanks.

**Update 1:** Seems like some other person has encountered almost the same -- [Android ndk-build error make.exe: *** create_child_process: DuplicateHandle(In) failed (e=6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873207/android-ndk-build-error-make-exe-create-child-process-duplicatehandlein)

I shall try the solution over there and give further updates on this.

**Update 2:** Still I am curios why it's different when one uses CreateProcess().
So, I'm still thinking. Any answers? I'm yet to try the suggested solution though.

Comment: Please show the full call to CreateProcess, including all the flags.  Is your application a command-line executable or a GUI executable?

Comment: STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = { 0 }; 
CreateProcess(NULL, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &procInfo);

Comment: Mine is a commmand-line executable trying to launch make.exe using CreateProcess().

Comment: Most curious.  I suspect a bug in `make` as the most likely cause.  Try something like `cmd.exe /c start cmd /c make -j8 some-component-name` (note that the doubling-up of cmd /c is deliberate, though it might not be necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I would want to capture the stdout and stderr of the created process which would need to inherit the parent console window handle. So, launching a separate window wouldn't help me in this I guess.

Comment: I imagine that someone's going to have to go spelunking inside `make.exe` to see exactly what's happening in order to work out how to run it successfully from `CreateProcess` without opening a new console.  But you could perhaps run `make` in a new console, but redirect the output to a temp file which your code can read?

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as "make version 2.anything".  The earliest documented release is 3.03 back in 1988 and there is no actual implementation of that version available anywhere.  The oldest _potentially_ buildable version is 3.55 released in 1989, and the first version that ran on Windows was 3.75 released in 1996.  Anyway.  I think you should email make-win@gnu.org and/or file a bug on http://savannah.gnu.org.  Asking questions and getting workarounds on StackOverflow is all very well but it doesn't actually help improve the software...

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I tried `cmd.exe /c start cmd /c make -j8 some-component-name` but didn't work. Same error. Redirecting the streams to a file from the command-prompt instead of programmatically didn't affect the failure either. But, thanks anyway for the inputs.

Comment: @MadScientist: There is some 2.something.something version of make.exe at my workplace which I am not sure where they got from. For the completeness sake and to know if other people are also facing exactly the same problem, I have posted here in SO. I am aware of the respective GNU mailing list. Thanks for reminding though. In fact, there are number of such reports across the internet. One such - http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-w32/2012-01/msg00015.html

Comment: So does `cmd.exe /c start cmd /c make -j8 some-component-name` work from the command line?  What about from the Start Menu?  Can you reproduce the problem with a small enough program to post the entire program?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Actually, I tried the simple `cmd.exe /c "make -j8 component-name"` manually from command-prompt. The problem didn't appear. So, `CreateProcess()` seems like doing something else that a manual command-prompt invocation doesn't do.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write "there is no such thing as GNU make version 2.something".  Either that make.exe is not GNU make, or someone renumbered it when they built it for some bizarre reason.

Comment: Please try `cmd.exe /c start cmd /c make -j8 some-component-name` from the command line.  The `start` might reintroduce the issue, and if so, that would be a very useful clue.